# Creating a loop with R

Tags: r

If I have a dataframe with match results (3 possible values) and probabilities, for example:

```
FTR     Probability
H       0.49
A       0.35
H       0.21
D       0.71
D       0.19
...
```

And I want for each  possible value of `Probability` to count the total no' of some `FTR` value. lets say `H`.
So I guess I should run a for loop that will run for every unique value of `Probability` and count the number of `H` in that group.

I tried doing that by writing:
`for (i in 1:unique(dataframe$Probability)) { count(group_by(dataframe, FTR)) }` which doesn't work because I guess the problem starts with `unique` cuz it can not run through actual values of `probability` but their index value.

Comment: Are you looking for `table`?

Comment: Maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group - not looping, but instead `aggregate()` or `tapply()`?

Comment: Yes! This is also good! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's say for data.frame is mydf

```
mydf <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
           FTR = c("H", "A", "H", "D", "D"),
   Probability = c(0.49, 0.35, 0.21, 0.71, 0.19)
)

with(mydf, table(Probability, FTR))
```

will get you this

```
           FTR
Probability A D H
       0.19 0 1 0
       0.21 0 0 1
       0.35 1 0 0
       0.49 0 0 1
       0.71 0 1 0
```

Comment: Better than what I wanted at first. Thanks!